# RadioButton invisivel com spinner

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para que ao evento change de uma spinner ele deixe visivel ou invisivel um radiobutton. Tenho o seguinte código. Mas não está funcionando.

```
 <RadioGroup 
                       android:id="@+id/radioGrupo"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioUsuario"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                            android:text="Usuário" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioNaoUsuario"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:text="Não usuário" />

                    </RadioGroup> 

private void ExibeUsuarioNaoUsuario()
{
    naoUsuario =(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioNaoUsuario);
    usuario =(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioUsuario);
    groupUsuarioNaoUsuario =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGrupo);
    spnTipoCliente = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTipoCliente);
    spnTipoCliente.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

            groupUsuarioNaoUsuario.setVisibility(RadioGroup.VISIBLE);
            //usuario.setVisibility(RadioButton.VISIBLE);
            //naoUsuario.setVisibility(RadioButton.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            usuario.setVisibility(RadioButton.INVISIBLE);
            naoUsuario.setVisibility(RadioButton.INVISIBLE);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Como sabe que o código não funciona? Tem certeza que o `onItemSelected` não está sendo chamado? Ou são os botões que não ficam invisível? Escondendo o `RadioGroup` e os `RadioButton` não funciona?

Comment: @Wakim tentei deixar invisivel apenas o radiogroup ou apenas as radiobuttons mas nao funcionaou. Quando mudo o item da spinner ele nao os torna visibel mesmo eu passando o setvisibilty. E esta sendo chamado sim concerteza.

Comment: Vou testar seu código aqui e ver se consigo reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` funciona no `RadioGroup`, é até melhor que setar a visibilidade para todos os `RadioButton's`.

O problema é o entendimento sobre o [`onNothingSelected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onNothingSelected(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E)).

Não conhecia de fato até agora, mas ele praticamente não é chamado quando o usuário toca sobre o `Spinner`, e sim quando a seleção anterior do usuário deixa de existir.

> Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated or when the adapter becomes empty.

Isso pode ser visto, quando você limpa o `Adapter` com alguma opção selecionada previamente.

Se a sua lógica é esconder quando determinado item for selecionado, talvez a melhor solução seja verificar o parâmetro `position` ou até mesmo o *label* se for algo mais seguro.